# Binance API GET request multiple values

Tags: get, request, binance, get-request

I am trying to send GET request with Binance API as below by using Postman. However I couldn't manage to get multiple values in symbol parameter. For example ETHUSDT and BTCUSDT - tried different syntax but none of them worked for me. How can I send GET request for multiple values? Or am I have to send GET request for each value?

```
{{url}}/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHUSDT
```

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972272/3436831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems best way to handle this get all prices as below and filter the symbols or in a loop send get request for each symbol we want to get.

```
{{url}}/api/v3/ticker/price
```

Answer (score 1):

the documentation says it is available to add multiple symbols but when you attempt to get more than one it breaks. its a backend issue, its not set up to handle multiple symbols. it should accept using

> symbols=["symbol", "symbol", symbol]

but it cant read that. reach out to Binance and tell them to update their api if you wish. i have tried to no avail.

Comment: It's working now: `https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbols=["ETHUSDT","SOLUSDT"]`