# Binance API - Several symbols/pairs in a code

Tags: python, binance

It does work with 1 crypto pair by coding
`symbol = 'XRPUSDT'`
but it doesn't work with 2 or more pairs.
Ways I tried are:

```
symbol = ['XRPUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT']

symbol = 'XRPUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT'

symbol = {
    "XRP/USDT": "XRP/USDT", 
    "DOGE/USDT": "DOGE/USDT"
    }

symbol = [(XRP/USDT, 'XRP/USDT'), (DOGE/USDT, 'DOGE/USDT')]
```

Unfortunately, none of above worked out.
Does anyone have any ideas for listing several crypto pairs, please?
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it within a loop:

```
symbols = ['XRPUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT']
for symbol in symbols:
    # Binance RESTful API
```

Here is a snippet code of how to send GET request to Binance API inside a loop:

```py
for symbol in symbols:
    candles = requests.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines", params={'symbol': symbol,
                                  'interval': interval,
                                  'startTime': start_time,
                                  'endTime': end_time}).json()
```

And here is a complete example:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

api_address = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines'
start_time = int(datetime(2021, 8, 20).timestamp()) * 1000
end_time = int(datetime(2021, 8, 30).timestamp()) * 1000
interval='1d'
symbols = ['XRPUSDT', 'DOGEUSDT']
for symbol in symbols:
  candles = requests.get(url=api_address,
                      params={'symbol': symbol,
                              'interval': interval,
                              'startTime': start_time,
                              'endTime': end_time})
  print(candles.json())
```

See documentation for more info https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#klinecandlestick-data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! When I use your snippet code, I get error message saying: "requests.get" is undefined(same happens to interval, start_time, end_time too). is it because of the json library?

Comment: @Bryan only needs the request library and be sure to set appropriate values for the input arguments. Please see the edited answer for a complete example.